# Fetching data from database using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to fetch data from database using PHP and Ajax, which is first encoded into JSON.

But data is not printed properly on the screen. It shows elements of four rows in single line separated by comma.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function()
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'demo2.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
          var name = data[0];
          var email = data[1];
          var msg = data[2];
          var date1 = data[3];
          $('#output').html("<div id='container'>" + name + " " + email + " " + msg + " " + date1 + "</div><br>");
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share data which you want to print and format to print

Comment: Provide your json coming from server

Comment: "_four rows in single line_" - How does that work? Either you get four rows or a single line

Comment: share the data which you are getting from demo2.php

Comment: try to display the data in console and check.

Comment: [["fahad","fahad@gmail.com","hello!","2018-02-13"],["chris","chris@gmail.com","hello","2018-02-04"],["robert","robert@gmail.com","hi there","2018-02-06"]]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function()
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'demo2.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
          // Iterate object:
          my_text=''
          $.each(obj, function(index, value) {
             console.log(value);
             my_text += value
          }); 

          // var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "email":"email@domain.com", "msg":"Hello"}');
          $('#output').html("<div id='container'>" + my_text + "</div><br>");
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fks3j500/

Comment: Provide additional info! Give json data, console output. Also make sure your output is in JSON format

Comment: [["fahad","fahad@gmail.com","hello!","2018-02-13"],["chris","chris@gmail.com","hello","2018-02-04"],["robert","robert@gmail.com","hi there","2018-02-06"]]

Comment: Your array does not have keys thats why, print(obj[1][1])

Comment: How to get keys for each values?

Comment: is there any way to make it associative array?

Comment: Yes! Check your backend script (php) or check the updated code

Comment: Ok Thanks for ur help